# `SCRIPT` tags are not allowed in HTMLBars templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi there and thank you for clicking my question.

I have just upgraded my application to the latest ember-cli release (`2.3.0-beta.1`) and now one (or more) of my templates messed with the build. What coming next seems like a trivial issue, yet I never fully got around to it very well, so I'm finally asking.

As the title suggests, I previously had `<script>` tags in my templates for minor things, such as a small jQuery conditional `append()` or anything doable by 2 or 3 lines of code. I never considered that enough motivation for creating a view, but in the meantime s**t got serious.

So, given the following snippet, what would be the recommended approach for keeping its functionality intact? Please do not mind the logic and motivation behind this specific code fragment, it's just an example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 valign-wrapper">
      <img class="materialboxed radius left" width="100" src="/default_avatar.jpg" alt="" />
      <h3>Welcome, Sarah Connor!</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
  });
</script>
```

Anything that won't break the existing (and anticipated?) conventions would do at this point. Thing is, I kept reading stuff on this subject but nothing had a clear stand on it, plus some quick hacks I suspect to be avoiding the conventions in use, therefore I wouldn't go for it.

I am well aware documentation is still young for anything 2.x in ember-cli and still has a long-ish road ahead. I might be able to help with it, once I figure out what to do myself.

Since this is a question that's 50/50 real issue and discussion on good practices, I'm considering posting on discuss.emberjs as well, if SO won't bring up any applicable solution / define the concepts behind in a clearer way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just import js file in index.html and call `materialbox()` there. That being said the Ember way of doing this would be to create component that would wrap materialbox library.

```
{{materialbox-img src='/default_avatar.jpg' class='radius left'}}

import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'img',
  attributeBindings: ['src'],
  didInsertElement() {
    this.$().materialbox();
  }
});
// this may not work as is, just example how it could be done
```

Comment: Isn't creating reusable components for one-time jobs a bit of overdoing it? Also, a view in this case looks a lot more reasonable, since it's already in the loop and I just have to tap into it and add some `didInsertElement` code.

Comment: Views are [deprecated](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html). In regards to one-time job. Even if you use materialbox only for one image in project it still serves its purpose as encapsulating component.

Comment: So the Ember take on things like this would be to create a big pile of reusable components, some of them reused, some not?

Comment: You made it sound really bad with `big pile of components` but in reality, how big is your pile going to be? My guess is something like five components for this type of decoration. Some of them may even already exist in form of addon.

Comment: well, in this specific case there's the "real" reusable components (around 5 to 7 of them) and around 6-7 small things that only exist because there's no other way. It certainly feels like something's missing from this landscape.

Comment: Components are not only for reuse anymore. Controllers are going to be [deprecated(sorry can't find proper source)](http://www.slideshare.net/mixonic/new-component-patterns-in-emberjs) and components with routes will be only place where to put logic. That moves components use to `make everything out of them` with added benefit of encapsulation and testability.

Comment: Well, that really sheds some light over the matter. I also found somewhere that controllers will be deprecated, but I thought it's gonna be in 2.0 and it didn't happen, then I thought they gave up the idea. Good to know and thank you so much for your time, much appreciated!